# In Mac Numbers is there a way to change the cell fill color depending on a match in different sheet?

Tags: mac, numbers

I want to change the cell fill color on one sheet depending if there is a match of information from another sheet. Here is what I am looking for:

If the P# in Sheet 1 matches the P# in Sheet 2 I want to change the cell fill color in Sheet 1 to be yellow.

[image: Sheet 1]

I would use either the "Player" name or "P#" for the match, whichever would be easier to implement.  I hope that makes sense.  At present when any Player (P#) is selected in Table 1 I manually change the cell fill color in Table 2.

Right now when I enter the P# 1 in Sheet 2 it autofills the Player Name into the sheet. I want to be able for the cell in Sheet 1 to be yellow if there is a match either with the P# or the Player Name (whichever is easier to match) from Sheet 2.

[image: Sheet 2]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, conditional highlighting in Numbers (Format->Conditional Highlighting) is not that sophisticated as of yet: a Numbers cell can be color-highlighted automatically only based on its own value.

If you really wish to have automatic coloring for a cell based on the values of other cells, albeit indirectly, one of the things you can do is, first, to add a column, for example, next to the column with the cells you wish to be compared with. Then, fill the cells in the new column with a formula, for example, yielding boolean values (True/False) based on the cell values to be compared with each other. Finally, use the options in Format->Conditional Highlighting to create a conditional highlighting rule which would include both the fill and font colors.

The screenshot below shows a simple example. If a cell in the A column has the same value with the cell at the same row in the B column, then the cell at the same row in the C column takes the value of TRUE. Otherwise, it takes the value of FALSE. Because I had a narrow column in this example, I chose bright green for both the fill and font colors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately if I try that I would have to redo too much of the rest of the sheet for the other formulas inside it. I will continue to manually change the cell fill color for now.